# isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) always return true when installed Twitter client

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

```
SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)
```

That's a method in the Social.framework.

The document say that the method returns a Boolean value indicating whether the service is accessible and at least one account is set up.

But when I installed Twitter client, the method always return true whether or not the account is added in the Settings.

I run a demo on real devices such as iPhone 6s with iOS 9.3, iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 9.0, iPhone 5s with iOS 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same  problem.and I use ACAccountStore to judge whether user has already set system twitter account

```
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
```